# Playwright test library - checkbox state

Tags: e2e-testing, playwright

Please, how to get the status a checkbox element in the Playwright E2E test library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`jsHandle.evaluate()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-jshandle#jshandleevaluatepagefunction-arg):

```js
const checkbox = await page.$('[type=checkbox]');
const checkboxState = await checkbox.evaluate(node => node.checked);
```

or [`page.$eval()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-elementhandle#elementhandleevalselector-pagefunction-arg):

```js
const checkboxState = await page.$eval('[type=checkbox]', node => node.checked);
```

or [`page.evaluate()`](https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#pageevaluatepagefunction-arg):

```js
const checkboxState = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const checkbox = document.querySelector('[type=checkbox]');
    return checkbox.checked;
});
```

If you have more of them, you can do it in one go as well:

```js
const checkboxStates = await page.evaluate(() => {
    const checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('[type=checkbox]');
    return [...checkboxes].map(c => c.checked);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
page.isChecked()
```

Please check the document:

https://playwright.dev/docs/api/class-page#page-is-checked